# Copying files from temporary internet cache in python

Tags: python, shutil

I'm copying files from the temporary internet files cache into a folder, in bulk using a python script. Using shutil to copy the full path to the os.cwd, it comes up with this error:

```
builtins.IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:  
'C:\\Users\\NICK\\AppData\\(no whitespace in path; only for readability)
Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\(no whitespace in path; only for readability)
Temporary Internet Files\\CONTENT.IE5\\04HT8Z5C\\024MS[1].png\\'
```

Is it because these files are hidden or something?

Comment: The trailing `\ ` in the filename looks really strange.  No idea.

Comment: That was a durr moment for me. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a backslash at the end of your file name so it is maybe treated as a path.